# How to delete flow created by another user in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

One of our user has created flow on item creation to send mail. Now as admin from where I can delete/remove that flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go the the Office 365 admin portal -> Admin centers -> Flow admin center.

There under environments, you see a list of environments. Choose your production environment -> Resources -> Flow.

There you should see a list of flows and you are able to manage them.

Comment: Hi Martijn, in Admin Centers I can see only SharePoint and Onedrive. I assume this is because, i have Admin rights only on SharePoint.

Comment: This admin center is the only option. I don't know if there's a specific role for the flow admin center.